# need to require that at least one of 9 checkboxes be checked

Tags: html, checkbox

I have a form that has a save button in it. I also have 10 checkboxes that I need to require the user to check at least one of them, then another set of 6 checkboxes that I need the user to check at least one of them. Is there a way to have a message pop up when the user tries to save the record without having made a selection in both of these areas?

Comment: What are we talking about? HTML?

Comment: Add more details about the environment like wb application, ios app/android app so that you get some help. Also provide some code to show where you need help.

Comment: Sorry, I should have thought of that, it is MS Access 2013, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a validated form with jQuery.

First thing is that your HTML will need a checkbox array like:

<input type="checkbox" name='cb[]' value='cb1'/>

<input type="checkbox" name='cb[]' value='cb2'/>

<input type="checkbox" name='cb[]' value='cb3'/>

<input type="checkbox" name='cb[]' value='cb4'/>

<input type="checkbox" name='cb[]' value='cb5'/>

```
if(jQuery('input[name=cb]:checked').length==0) { 
   console.log('Please check at least one checkbox');
}
```

Something like that...For your other checkbox group, use a different name like name="cb2[]" and jQuery would be:

```
if(jQuery('input[name=cb2]:checked').length==0) { 
   console.log('Please check at least one checkbox');
}
```

I hope this helps.